# Mach Time stops counting when ios device sleeps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Basically, to get the absolute time of iOS device, I need to use mach_absolute_time(). From another resource, I found out that MachTime starts counting when the device "reboots". I assume it means only when turning off and restart the device completely, MachTime will reset and then run all the time.

However, what I experience was, MachTime stops counting when the device sleeps for a while, and resumes when you wake the device up. That means MachTime is not reliable to be used as a clock counting.

Is there anyone experienced the same problem?

Thanks for reading.

Source:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I just want to create an independent clock which can't be altered in Settings. It should keep running even when user sleeps the device.

Comment: Why does it need to keep running? What functionality is it providing?

Comment: Just assume a stopwatch as the default one in iPhone. When user starts the clock, it may not be affected by any other factors (like changing time in Settings, sleeps the device) unless user manually stops it. Otherwise the record time will be inaccurate. Apple default stopwatch doesn't accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

If `mach_absolute_time` doesn't do what you want, try using a different API.  [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452-CH201-F12326) seems like a good candidate.

Comment: According to Apple Time Utilities Reference about CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent: The system time may decrease due to synchronization with external time references or due to an explicit user change of the clock. Therefore, it would be altered as well, anyway thanks for your suggestion :)